# How to get the total count of records from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get the total count of rows from Sqlite DB. Following is the code snippet of what I am trying to do.

I dont know what I am doing wrong here ?

```
public static int getTotalCount(Context _context)
{
Cursor c = null;
try
{
    c = getInstance(_context).db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(word) FROM  "
        + WORD_TABLE, null);

    return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(WORD_COL));

} catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e("getTotalCount", e.toString());
}
return 0;
```

Exception message :
05-08 05:21:19.934: ERROR/getTotalCount(440): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `c.getInt(0);`

or

```
 c = getInstance(_context).db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(word) as WORD_COL FROM  "
    + WORD_TABLE, null);
```

also put a `c.moveToFirst();` right after the rawQuery line for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `WORD_COL` is `word`? You have not requested a column named `word`. You have a column `COUNT(word)`, which is a completely different matter; thus when you try to fetch data for `word`, `getColumnIndex` fails to find it, giving you a nonsense index of `-1`, which then causes the `getInt` to fail since nobody counts from `-1` up. :)

You can rename the column to something nicer, too: `SELECT COUNT(word) AS word_count FROM...`, then request that name. Another option is, you know this query returns only one column, there is no need to name it; just use its index directly.

Answer (score 1):

After the `rawQuery`, try

```
c.moveToFirst();
return c.GetInt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

try out this:

```
Cursor c  = _sqlDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from table", null);
System.out.println("Count:"+c.getCount());
```

regards,
Nital Shah

Comment: this will fetch all the rows in the table, he only wanted to know the count.

Comment: it doesn't matter.. The cost difference of quering simple or more complicated query (just count or fetch data) whith small amount of data is so little that it pays of more to fetch everything and count results.. Then later he can even use results without quering again

Answer (score 0):

You may have this `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the cursor doesnt point to the first result.

Try this:

```
try
{
    c = getInstance(_context).db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(word) FROM  "
        + WORD_TABLE, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(WORD_COL));

} catch (Exception e)
```