# How to count the number of records by using a specific column in a Cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wrote an app which contains a SQLite database and having a table named "notification".
I want to get the record count by using the column named "packageName" from the afore mentioned table.

How do I do that?

code:

```
 public long getRecordsCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CNotificationDataBaseTableDeclarations.NotificationsTable.TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: sqlite3 has a `count` function `select count (*) from Table`

Comment: i am using sqlite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the total count of records from SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925790/how-to-get-the-total-count-of-records-from-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
public long getRecordsCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        String selectQuery =
                "SELECT COUNT(*)" +
                " FROM " + CNotificationDataBaseTableDeclarations.NotificationsTable.TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + YOUR_SPECIFIC_COLUMN + " = 'COLUMN_VALUE'";
        return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, selectQuery, null);
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of [queryNumEntries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) that allows you to use the same `selection` filtering as with a normal query:

```java
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,
                    CNotificationDataBaseTableDeclarations.NotificationsTable.TABLE_NAME,
                    YOUR_SPECIFIC_COLUMN + " = 42", null);
```

or for a string value:

```java
                    ...
                    YOUR_SPECIFIC_COLUMN + " = ?", new String[]{ "your value" });
```